# Principal Component Analysis Question - Why do the Loadings Not Change As You Change the Number of PCs?

Tags: r, classification, pca, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to teach myself how to use R Shiny and as a part of this dashboard I'm constructing, I have a section where a user performs principal component analysis and can use a slider to choose the number of PCs to include.

Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
PCA=preProcess(to_be_PCAed, method = "pca", pcaComp = input$num)
rots=round(PCA$rotation,6)
```

The user will use the slider to choose from 20 PCs down to just 2.  Whenever I display the matrix of loadings, the individual loadings for each variable do not change within a PC when I add or subtract another PC.  Is that how Principal Component analysis should work?  What am I missing here?  My original thought was that the loadings determined which PC a variable would be classified under and I would think that the variables would be grouped together differently based on the number of principal components.  So, I was expecting as I add or subtract a PC, the loadings would change.

Can someone explain why this is not the case?

Comment: [First component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#First_component), [further components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Further_components)

Comment: Your question is very vague. You might attack an answer if the question was more focussed. (The actual question is focussed, but the title is quite open ended.)

Comment: The components are determined by the directions of maximum covariance. That is fixed by the data. They are fixed so if you ask for 10 you, the first 2 will be identical to as the first 2 if you only ask for 3. UNLESS you are rotating the extracted components. Then 2 components rotated will generally not be identical to the first 2 components of 10 rotated.

Comment: PCA is a description, not modeling technique: we extract m PCs from the data and do not fit m PCs to the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate questions here: (1) Running Shiny, and (2) interpreting PCA.

Your Shiny app works fine.

And your PCA is correct.

I'm guessing that you come from the social sciences, like me, where principal components analysis is usually followed by rotation of the components. The default rotation is VariMax but there are several others methods. Then the technique is called Factor Analysis.

I used to help my students to understand PCA with this simple analogy:

Imagine a ship taken into harbour pulled by two, or more, tugboats, each pulling with the same strength, but in slightly different directions. Draw it on a piece of paper. Now, in what direction and with what strength is the ship heading? It's the resolution of the pull of the different tugboats. That is the first Principal Component. In two dimensions, x & y, we can defie the effort of the tugboats in terms of vectors along xy. After removing the first Principal Component there is still some pull in the xy plane. That's the second Principal Component. Now, if we move into three dimensions, and change our analogy to a Startreck tractor beam, then we might have a third PC. Logically, the first PC will always be larger than all folowing PCs.

Comment: As physical analogies go, this one doesn't work.  Classical mechanics (Newton's Laws) imply there is a net force from all the tugboats, *and that's it.*  There isn't any additional "some pull" in the plane.

Comment: Agreed. But the analogy helps students understand the notion of resolution of forces. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Unfortunately, PCA bears little relationship to resolution of forces.  All they have in common is the concept of a vector, which provides no additional insight into PCA.